# It seems to me that draw is all Black can get, but maybe I am wrong?

Tags: analysis

Recently I have played a game against a computer and came to the following position :

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "3r4/p3Q1pk/1pp3p1/8/3qP3/P7/1P3RPP/6K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

I have played `...Rd7` and soon the game ended as a draw by threefold repetition.

Was I able to win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see a thing, and nether did Stockfish.

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "3r4/p3Q1pk/1pp3p1/8/3qP3/P7/1P3RPP/6K1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rd6 2.Qh4+ (2.Qxa7?? Rf6 ) Kg8 3.Qh3 Qe5 4.Qc8+ Kh7 5.Qh3+ Qh5 6.Qxh5+ gxh5 7.b4 Kg6 8.Rf8 Rd4 9.Rc8 Rc4 10.Ra8 Rxe4 11.Rxa7 Rc4 12.Kf2 Rc2+ 13.Kf3 b5 14.a4 bxa4 15.Rxa4 h4 16.Ra6 Kf5 17.Ra5+ Kf6=
```

Just because there's no forced win doesn't mean the game is without tension and opportunity. I have lost games similar to this game after move 12.

Comment: Actually, I would force threefold repetition with `5...Kg8` instead going through rook endgame. I relied on `1...Rd6` to offer winning chances but since I have no chess software at the moment installed, I needed a confirmation. If `1...Rd6` fails to achieve win then it indeed is a draw. Thank you for your help. +1 Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In this position, I would be pleased to draw as Black.

On the Queen side, Black does have the advantage of three pawns to two. But Black's pawns aren't particularly far forward, and White can contain them easily.

On the king side, White has two healthy pawns against two doubled pawns. The preponderance is more like 2 to 1 (White), than 2 to 2.

In the center, White is a clear passed pawn ahead, giving him an advantage in terms of pawn structure.

Black does have a countervailing advantage in terms of his grip on the Q file. But if he tries to "chase" White's pawns, he can do so only at the cost of relinquishing this advantage. I've seen more games lost than won when someone gives up a real advantage in order to pursue an illusory advantage, thereby allowing his opponent's advantages to prevail.

A "draw by repetition" often occurs because the "repeated" positions are optimal for both sides. You deviate from your optimum position at your own risk. Grandmaster Richard Reti once lost an important tournament game to Alexander Alekhine (the future world champion) by declining a draw by repetition.